# Is it possible that C# has problems calling VB6 methods that have optional parameters?

Tags: c#, interface, com, vb6, typelib

I added 3 optional boolean parameters to a method found within a VB6 DLL. The class that houses it is MultiUse (public), and the method itself is Private. The class implements a specific interface from a TLB, allowing for public calls to this method.

After adding the 3 optional parameters on the VB6 side, I modified related C# code so that it specified the 3 optional parameters. It built fine... however, when I try to run that code, it fails with the following error message:

> Method not found: 'Boolean
>   MyTLBName.IMyClassName.MyMethod(System.Object,
>   System.String, Boolean, Boolean,
>   Int32, Int32 ByRef, System.Object,
>   System.Object, System.Object, Boolean,
>   Boolean, Boolean)'.

Notice how all 3 boolean parameters are shown in the error message? Looks fine to me... I know I specified those 3 booleans when calling the method from C#.

Suspicious, I checked out the MyTLBName.IMyClassName interface in OLEView, and saw this:

[id(0x60030000)]

```
HRESULT MyMethod(
                //Cut out the other parameters - they are working fine.
                [in, optional, defaultvalue(-1)] VARIANT_BOOL blnMyFirstOptionalBoolean, 
                [in, optional, defaultvalue(-1)] VARIANT_BOOL blnMySecondOptionalBoolean, 
                [in, optional, defaultvalue(-1)] VARIANT_BOOL blnMyThirdOptionalBoolean, 
                [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* __MIDL_0324);
```

Again, the 3 optional parameters are visible, and look fine.

Seems to me like it should work... but maybe I'm missing something.

Is there any way I can get this working without having to create another version of "MyMethod" in the TLB? (With a different name, and those 3 parameters as required rather than optional)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, C# does have problems calling VB6 functions with optional parameters.  I fought very hard with this one on a project where I absolutely needed to use the VB6 component provided by an external vendor.

I found that the easiest solution was to create a class in VB to call those functions, since VB.Net DOES support optional parameters, and then call that VB6 class from C#.

In the class written in VB.Net, I followed the proper method overloading to provide several methods to call that one VB6 function.

Example - say the VB6 function has three parameters, the first one required, and the second two optional, I'd create three functions in the VB.Net component.

```
Public Sub CallComponent(byVal myParameter as Integer)
  ....call component with one parm
End Sub

Public Sub CallComponent(byVal myParameter as Integer, byVal parm2 as  String,)
  ....call component with two parms
End Sub
```

etc...

And it looks like optional parameters are coming in 4.0: [http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/02/05/c-4.0-optional-parameters.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026022658/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/02/05/c-4.0-optional-parameters.aspx)

Comment: The tech republic link is broken.